# Accessing a Java object in a Java object in C using JNI

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

I'm relatively new to JNI and have gotten down the basics of messing with integers and arrays in Java objects using JNI.  Now I'm trying to modify/access a Java object within a Java object.

I've been searching on the internet and on Stack Overflow and have yet to find out how to do this.

Here's the example.

In Java:

```
public class ObjectOne
{
    private byte[] buff;
    ...
    ...
}

public class ObjectTwo
{
    private ObjectOne obj;
    ...
    ...
}
```

In JNI, how do I access "buff" from ObjectOne through ObjectTwo?  I tried something like this...

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_accessBuffThroughObjectTwo(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject objectTwo)
{
    jclass clazz;
    jclass bufferClazz;
    jobject bufferJObject;

    clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, objectTwo);
    fid = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, clazz, "obj", "Ljava/lang/Object;");
    bufferJObject = (*env)->GetObjectField(env, javascsicommand, fid);
    bufferClazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, bufferJObject);  <-- Fails here for Access Violation
    fid = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, bufferClazz, "buff", "[B");
}
```

Any help on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: First step is to check each JNI call to see if it is failing. Second: what is `javascsicommand`?

Comment: I believe you're passing the wrong value for the `obj` instance to [GetObjectField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16572).
See the correct descriptor:
`jobject GetObjectField(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jfieldID fieldID);`

Comment: Perhaps you meant to pass `objectTwo` rather than `javascsicommand`?

Comment: You cannot access the private fields of the other object. You need to provide getter, change access right keyword, or open the access runtime.

Comment: @qrtt1 Yes you can access private fields using JNI.

Comment: @maba I mean the private field of the **other** object.

Comment: @veer yeah sorry I meant objectTwo rather than javascsicommand.  It was a bad copy and paste without proper "refactoring".  :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When trying your code you could easily add some assertions like this:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_accessBuffThroughObjectTwo(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,  jobject objectTwo) {
    jclass clazz;
    jclass bufferClazz;
    jobject bufferJObject;
    jfieldID fid;

    clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, objectTwo);
    assert(clazz != NULL);
    fid = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, clazz, "obj", "Ljava/lang/Object;");
    assert(fid != NULL);
    bufferJObject = (*env)->GetObjectField(env, javascsicommand, fid);
    assert(bufferJObject != NULL);
    bufferClazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, bufferJObject);
    assert(bufferClazz != NULL);
    fid = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, bufferClazz, "buff", "[B");
    assert(fid != NULL);
}
```

Doing so you will first see that the first `fid` will be NULL. That is because the `ObjectTwo` class does not have any fields of type `java.lang.Object`. You should change the line to look like this (but add the correct packages instead of `com/package`):

```
fid = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, clazz, "obj", "Lcom/package/ObjectOne;");
```

If you run again you will find that the fid is no longer null and the assertion will pass.

As others have suggested I believe that the `javascsicommand` should be `objectTwo`.

Now the next place where the assertion will fail is on `bufferJObject`. That is because the field exists but the object is NULL and if you check your java code you will notice that the `obj` field is never instantiated and is `null`.

Change your java code to something like this:

```
public class ObjectTwo
{
    private ObjectOne obj = new ObjectOne();
    ...
    ...
}
```

You will now pass the assertion and even pass all other assertions.

To summarize you were accessing a `null` object and trying to invoke reflection on it:

```
bufferClazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, bufferJObject); <-- The bufferJObject was NULL
```

Comment: thanks for this detailed response.  I will definitely utilize the assertions and check for NULL.  I think you hit the nail on the head when you were talking about accessing a null object.  I think that's what's giving me the access violation

Comment: @user1575243 If you think that my answer was useful then please mark the answer as accepted!

Comment: @user1575243 If people like myself spend some time to set up coding environments, start debugging sessions and try to solve other peoples problems then the least you can expect from them is that they accept answers that they find useful...

Comment: Sorry about this.  I didn't know that accepting answers was so valued.  Answer accepted.