# JNI - GetObjectField failed for class inside class

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I'm trying to access a Java object within a Java object. I've looked at [Accessing a Java object in a Java object in C using JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803927/accessing-a-java-object-in-a-java-object-in-c-using-jni), but my app still gets an error in `GetObjectField`.

The error is:

```
sart/tuntime/check_jni:.cc65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: 
jfieldID my.package.name.SubObject my.package.name.MainObject.subObject
not valid for an object of class java.lang.Class<my.package.name.MainObject>
```

My code is:

**MainObject**

```
package my.package.name;
public class MainObject {
    SubObject subObject= new SubObject();
}
```

**SubObject**

```
package my.package.name;
public class SubObject {
    String name;
}
```

**JNI**

```
void ReadJavaObject(JNIEnv * env,  jobject mainObjectJava)
{
    jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(mainObjectJava);   
    jfieldID subObjectID = env->GetFieldID(cls, "subObject", "Lmy/package/name/SubObject;");
    jobject subObjectJava= env->GetObjectField(cls, subObjectID);
//...Do something with subObjectJava
}
```

Comment: Where is the JNI call `ReadJavaObject`?

Comment: @SimonMarquis - what do you mean?

Comment: I was refering the code where you actually call `xyz.ReadJavaObject(...)` but nevermind, I've added the solution ;)

Comment: There is zero error checking here. You cannot write JNI code like this. You have to check the result of every JNI API call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you simply used the wrong parameter on the last call.
`GetObjectField` must be used with the root object and the objectId to get.

```
void ReadJavaObject(JNIEnv * env,  jobject mainObjectJava)
{
    jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(mainObjectJava);   
    jfieldID subObjectID = env->GetFieldID(cls, "subObject", "Lmy/package/name/SubObject;");
    jobject subObjectJava= env->GetObjectField(mainObjectJava, subObjectID);
}
```